# Are there any good ways of stopping, avoiding or killing "cat bombs" (catting a large file) when using a remote session ssh or tmux?

Tags: ssh, tmux, remote, cat

A common problem is when you have a remote session open (ssh or tmux for example) and you accidentally cat a large file. The screen starts dumping text and you can't kill it. I am guessing those udp sessions might be better for this but are there any simply tricks for either avoiding this problem (besides not catting large files on remotes) or killing the screen dump effectively.

Comment: use *head* instead of *cat*

Comment: Make a second SSH connection and then find and kill the cat process. I imagine "killall cat" would work.

Comment: Stop using cat and use less (or more). Depending on your behaviour, maybe set an alias for cat to less?

Comment: @davidgo I guess we really need one command that is just cat if short enough and less if longer than some amount. Seems stupid, but retraining the human is hard :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mosh` is an alternative shell program to ssh.

The official [website](https://mosh.org/) goes through the various benefits below.  Particularly the last solves is your problem but also many other benefits.  Installation varies by distro with [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-mosh-on-a-vps) showing how to open up the relevant UDP ports (default: 60000-61000) for most distros.  Only drawback would be some extra work for scrollback (it syncs screen state so scrollback hard in princple) but you mention tmux which can solve that.

- Change IP. Stay connected.

Mosh automatically roams as you move between Internet connections. Use Wi-Fi on the train, Ethernet in a hotel, and LTE on a beach: you'll stay logged in. Most network programs lose their connections after roaming, including SSH and Web apps like Gmail. Mosh is different.

- Makes for sweet dreams.

With Mosh, you can put your laptop to sleep and wake it up later, keeping your connection intact. If your Internet connection drops, Mosh will warn you — but the connection resumes when network service comes back.

- Get rid of network lag.

SSH waits for the server's reply before showing you your own typing. That can make for a lousy user interface. Mosh is different: it gives an instant response to typing, deleting, and line editing. It does this adaptively and works even in full-screen programs like emacs and vim. On a bad connection, outstanding predictions are underlined so you won't be misled.

- No privileged code. No daemon.

You don't need to be the superuser to install or run Mosh. The client and server are executables run by an ordinary user and last only for the life of the connection.

- Same login method.

Mosh doesn't listen on network ports or authenticate users. The mosh client logs in to the server via SSH, and users present the same credentials (e.g., password, public key) as before. Then Mosh runs the mosh-server remotely and connects to it over UDP.

- Runs inside your terminal, but better.

Mosh is a command-line program, like ssh. You can use it inside xterm, gnome-terminal, urxvt, Terminal.app, iTerm, emacs, screen, or tmux. But mosh was designed from scratch and supports just one character set: UTF-8. It fixes Unicode bugs in other terminals and in SSH.

- Control-C works great.

Unlike SSH, mosh's UDP-based protocol handles packet loss gracefully, and sets the frame rate based on network conditions. Mosh doesn't fill up network buffers, so Control-C always works to halt a runaway process.

Comment: Someone recommended mosh to me and it looks great I just haven't fully bought in yet as it felt like a bit of infra that required setup so it's sort of not in my vanilla set of tools.

Comment: Its definitely worth it; I added in link to install/setup instructions for popular distro.   Mark the answer as accepted solution if this fixes your cat bomb issues.